# Add body to a HTTP post request with node in a functional way

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-request

I have the following code in a test:

```
var req = request(App)
  .post(postUrl)
  .set('Authorization', authorizationToken);

req.expect(201)
  .end(done);
```

And I want to add a `body` to the request.

I can't find any possible way to do it maintaining this style, the only way I found is by creating an object with all the proper data inside and then pass it to the request. Is it possible to add it?

Comment: What's in `done` variable? Are you talking about request body, the thing after `\r\n\r\n`?

Comment: `done` is the callback, it's the typical CB name for mocha tests. I'm talking about request body, of course

Comment: I never used `node-request`, but I'd start here: https://github.com/request/request#forms Unless you need to send raw data, it's straight answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use supertest library, then if you want send post data you should do like this:

```
var postData = {
   "field":1,
   "field1": "test"
};

var req = request(App)
  .post(postUrl)
  .set('Authorization', authorizationToken)
  .send(postData);
```